# VBA Looping/Logic Issue

Tags: string, excel, vba, loops

I am writing a macro in excel for work and I am having trouble.  In this scenario there are two sheets, "BU" and "TOPS Information".  When the macro is used it is supposed to search every line of "BU" for the value found in "TOPS Information", then go to the next line of "TOPS Information and repeat the process.  If it finds a correct match it is supposed to copy a cell and paste it into "TOPS Information".

Here is the code:

```
Sub QIM()

Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim searchArray(1 To 3) As String

j = 0
k = 1



'WARNING: Temporary Sheet Names
lastRowTOPS = Worksheets("TOPS Information").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowBU = Worksheets("BU").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Cycle through BU rows
For j = lastRowTOPS To 1 Step -1

    'Cycle through searchArray for each BU row
    For k = lastRowBU To 1 Step -1


            '//////////////////////////////////////

            x = Sheets("BU").Range("B" & k).Value
            y = Range("C" & j).Value

            If StrComp(x, y) = 1 Then



                Sheets("BU").Range("C" & k).Copy
                Range("H" & j).PasteSpecial



            End If

            '//////////////////////////////////////



    Next k

Next j


End Sub
```

This Macro obviously only works if "TOPS Information" is selected at the time.  Any and all help would be most appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: [http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx](vlookup) might be what you are looking for

Comment: broken link.  [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx
Thanks @JimmySmith

Comment: Will there be duplicate values in sheet `BU` column B? Your code will end up copy the top most "finding". If col B data are unique, then `Exit For` to reduce the execute time. You should consider using 2 worksheet variable and 2 Range variables.

Answer (score 1):

You sorta answered it yourself.  Range refers to the current sheet, but when you're bouncing around then you have to qualify it.

Prefix your ranges with the appropriate sheet like so,

```
Sub QIM()

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    Dim searchArray(1 To 3) As String

    j = 0
    k = 1



    'WARNING: Temporary Sheet Names
    lastRowTOPS = Worksheets("TOPS Information").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowBU = Worksheets("BU").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Cycle through BU rows
    For j = lastRowTOPS To 1 Step -1

        'Cycle through searchArray for each BU row
        For k = lastRowBU To 1 Step -1
                '//////////////////////////////////////
                x = Sheets("BU").Range("B" & k).Value
                y = Sheets("TOPS Information").Range("C" & j).Value
                If StrComp(x, y) = 1 Then
                    Sheets("BU").Range("C" & k).Copy
                    Sheets("TOPS Information").Range("H" & j).PasteSpecial
                End If

                '//////////////////////////////////////

        Next k

    Next j


    End Sub
```

Comment: +1 ... but I'm getting tired of answering this question over & over again :) perhaps we need a canonical answer for `Method Range of Worksheet Object Failed` error...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only want to copy the top most found data in `BU` to `TOPS`, you can use below.

```
Sub QIM()
    Dim oWS_TOPS As Worksheet, oWS_BU As Worksheet ' Worksheet objects
    Dim oRng_TOPS As Range, oRng_BU As Range ' Range objects
    Dim R_TOPS As Long, R_BU As Long

    Set oWS_TOPS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TOPS Information") ' <-- Replace this "TOPS Information" to match future changes
    Set oWS_BU = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BU") ' <-- Replace this "BU" to match future changes

    R_TOPS = oWS_TOPS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    R_BU = oWS_BU.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Search column B of BU for each cell in column C of TOPS
    For Each oRng_TOPS In oWS_TOPS.Columns("C").Cells ' <-- Replace this "C" to match future changes
        ' Exit if row is more than last A column data
        If oRng_TOPS.Row > R_TOPS Then Exit For
        For Each oRng_BU In oWS_BU.Columns("B").Cells ' <-- Replace this "B" to match future changes
            ' Exit if row is more than last A column data
            If oRng_BU.Row > R_BU Then Exit For
            ' Check if Ranges match (## See Update ##)
            If InStr(1, oRng_TOPS.Value, oRng_BU.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' Copy column C of found row in BU to column H of TOPS, then exit
                oWS_BU.Cells(oRng_BU.Row, "C").Copy oWS_TOPS.Cells(oRng_TOPS.Row, "H") ' <-- Replace these "C" and "H" to match future changes
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Set oWS_TOPS = Nothing
    Set oWS_BU = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are many ways to achieve your goal, and this is one of it.

---

**UPDATE** Note on comparing cell values (String):

`StrComp(S1,S2[,mode])` only return 3 values {-1, 0, 1} to indicate if S1 is less/equal/greater than S2. If you want an exact match (case sensitive and exact spacing), use `If StrComp(S1,S2) = 0 Then`.

`InStr([i,]S1,S2[,mode])` only returns positive values - it returns the character location of first appearance of S2 in S1. If S2 is not found then it returns zero.

You can also use `Trim(sText)` to remove leading/ending spaces of sText.

Hope below screenshot says more.

[image: strcomp vs instr]

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry for asking a previously answered question, I am new to VBA and could not figure out how other answers applied.  Cheers!

Comment: Quick question though, if I wanted to compare entire strings, not just check if one string is in the other, how could I do that.  I tried using strcomp, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You can use `If oRng_TOPS.Value = oRng_BU.Value Then` for exact match, or check on Update of my answer.